# SQL query to get unique values from repeating rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have on table:

```
Roll_No Subject  Marks  Percentage
1       Maths    75     70
1       Science  70     70
1       History  65     70
2       Maths    89     90
2       Science  91     90
2       History  90     90
3       Maths    50     55
3       Science  55     55
3       History  60     55
```

I want to get 2 outputs in 1st query as:

```
Roll No sum(marks)  Percentage
1       210         70
2       270         90
3       165         55
```

I want to achieve 2nd output from base table as: 
Count(roll_no), Sum(Marks), Sum(Percentage---This should be one value for one student).

```
3    645(sum of all marks)    215 (i.e 70+90+55)
```

Can you please help me or guide me to achieve result.

Comment: This is a basic aggregation query.  If you are going to use SQL effectively, you should learn the basics of the language, and `group by` is basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
select roll_no, sum(marks), max(percentage)
from table
group by roll_no
```

To the second part of your question:

```
select count(roll_no), sum(marks), max(percentage)
from (select roll_no, sum(marks) as marks, max(percentage) as percentage
      from table
      group by roll_no)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help jherran...can you please help me to achieve following in the same :                                count(Roll_No) sum(Marks) Sum(Percentage group by roll no)
3 645 215 : itried to achieve this but not getting from 1st table

Comment: Sorry to bother you again jherran :( ....I am not able to get sum of percentage here...when i tried it is giving me mix of aggregate and non-aggregate error. I wanted to show sum of percentage of three students that is 70+90+65 with all sum of marks and count of student.

Comment: It is repeating the percentage values so it is taking sum of all percentage and not only 70+90+65. It is taking sum as 3(70+90+65).

Comment: with cte as
(
select Roll_No,Sum(Marks) as Marks ,Max(Percentage) as Percent from table group by Roll_No
)
select count(Roll_No),Sum(Marks),Sum(Percent) from cte;

Comment: Thanks Spider..inner query of cte worked for me...Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select Roll_No,Sum(Marks),Max(Percentage) from table group by Roll_No;

with cte as
(
select Roll_No,Sum(Marks) as Marks ,Max(Percentage) as Percent from table group by Roll_No
)
select count(Roll_No),Sum(Marks),Sum(Percent) from cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) and [SUM](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp) function. I think this should help:

```
SELECT Roll_No, SUM(Marks), Percentage FROM table GROUP BY Percentage
```